# Reading htm file to .HTMLBody VBA

Tags: html, vba, email

I'm attempting to automate an email using an Excel worksheet and VBA. I'm able to copy the desired range into the email, but I want to use a htm file for the HTML formatting.

How do I read a htm file and add it to the .HTMLBody of my email?

Here's my code, which sends an email with the correct worksheet, but does not include the HTML formatting that is added with the test(path) function:

```
Sub Send_To_Outlook()
    Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim Sendrng As range
    Dim rng As range
    Dim text As String
    Dim textline As String
    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = "H:\My Documents\email.htm"

    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Fill in the Worksheet/range you want to mail
    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Email").range("C6:L244")

    'Remember the activesheet
    Set AWorksheet = ActiveSheet

    With Sendrng

        ' Select the worksheet with the range you want to send
        .Parent.Select

        'Remember the ActiveCell on that worksheet
        Set rng = ActiveCell

        'Select the range you want to mail
        .Select

        ' Create the mail and send it
        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope


            With .Item
                .To = "myemail@email.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "My subject"
                .HTMLBody = test(sPath)
                .Send
            End With

        End With

        'select the original ActiveCell
        rng.Select
    End With

    'Activate the sheet that was active before you run the macro
    AWorksheet.Select

StopMacro:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub


Function test(sPath As String)

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFS As Object, sText As String

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sPath)

    test= oFS.ReadAll()

End Function
```

Any suggestions or advice on why this isn't working would be awesome!

PS I also need to display the message instead of send, but this isn't as important of an issue.

Comment: Do you know where exactly your code is having problems? What sort of error you might be getting (if any)?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't very useful to help us help you: what exactly happens when you run your code?

Comment: Sorry! My code sends an email with the correct worksheet, but does not include the HTML formatting that is added with the `test(path)` function

Answer (score 2):

Your function doesn't return any value.
Try this:

```
Function test(sPath As String)
    test = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath).ReadAll()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say that your code doesn't work, does that mean that you get an error or that the code executes but the email body is empty?

I would first check to see if your "test" Function is returning a null string:

```
Function test(sPath As String)

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFS As Object, sText As String

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sPath)

' I don't think you need to loop until EOF with .ReadAll
sText = oFS.ReadAll

' This will print sText to the Immediate Window; if it is 0, then sText is null         
Debug.Print ("sText string has a length of: " & Len(sText))


End Function
```

My guess is that sText is null.  If it is reading the .htm successfully, I would next check to make sure that the .htm is valid .html syntax.

Comment: The function doesn't return any value.  It needs `test = [file content]`, but the value is being assigned to `sText`

Comment: ah you are correct... this probably was her original issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on debug.print, I was able to see that the function is returning a string with a length of 224495. However, the formatting isn't showing up in the email. I copied the html from the original email. I imagine since it works in the original email it should theoretically work in this one?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. There was an issue when using html coupled with sending the worksheet range in the above code. I decided to covert the worksheet into html, export the chart into an image and insert it into the rest of the html for the email.

```
    Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng1 As range
    Dim rng2 As range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim newimage As Action
    Dim aPath As String
    Dim bPath As String
    Dim sPath As String

    'Name the variables for your the needed paths
    sPath = "C:\Chart1.png"
    aPath = "C:\email1.htm"
    bPath = "C:\email2.htm"

    'Export your chart as an image
    Call ExportChart("Chart1")

    'Select the range your desired tables are in
    Set rng1 = Worksheets("Email").range("C6:L32")
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Email").range("C45:L244")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Create the email
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "myemail@email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        ' Place your tables in the correct location of your html for the email
        .HTMLBody = test(aPath) & RangetoHTML(rng1) & "<img src=" & "'" & sPath & "'" & "width=888; height=198>" & RangetoHTML(rng2) & test(bPath)
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
Function ExportChart(sChartName As String)

      '   Export a selected chart as a picture
        Const sSlash$ = "/"
        Const sPicType$ = ".png"
        Dim sPath$
        Dim sBook$
        Dim objChart As ChartObject


        On Error Resume Next
         '   Test if there are even any embedded charts on the activesheet
         '   If not, let the user know
        Set objChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
        If objChart Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No charts have been detected on this sheet", 0
            Exit Function
        End If

         '   Test if there is a single chart selected
        If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "You must select a single chart for exporting ", 0
            Exit Function
        End If

Start:

         '   chart is exported as a picture, Chart1.png in the same
         '   folder location as the workbook
        sBook = ActiveWorkbook.path
        sPath = sBook & sSlash & sChartName & sPicType
        ActiveChart.Export Filename:=sPath, FilterName:="PNG"


        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False

        End With

End Function

Function RangetoHTML(rng As range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function

Function test(sPath As String)
    'Returns a string after reading the contents of a given file
    test = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath).ReadAll()

End Function
```

Thanks for all of your help! :)