# Remove the signature when opening an Outlook template in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to open an Outlook template (.oft) file from Excel but without appending the user's signature. I can't get this to work.

I know I need to delete the hidden bookmark "_MailAutoSig" but I can't figure out how. I've tried to follow this guide but it's out of date and doesn't work with Outlook / Excel 2016: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/dd492012(v=office.12)#176-working-with-outlook-signatures

Here is my code

```
Option Explicit

Sub openEmail()

Dim cfgFromEmail As String
Dim cfgNotice As String
Dim cfgTemplate As String
Dim appOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim newEmail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim rownum As Integer
Dim colnum As Integer

rownum = 6

cfgFromEmail = Sheets("Email").Range("O5").Value
cfgNotice = Sheets("Email").Cells(rownum, 10) '10 = column J
cfgTemplate = Sheets("Email").Cells(rownum, 11) '11 = column K

Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = appOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\location\to\template\" & cfgTemplate & ".oft")
'Set template = mailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'Creates a blank email

If cfgNotice <> "null" Then 'If is not blank
    MsgBox cfgNotice, vbInformation, "Before you send the email"
End If

With newEmail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = cfgFromEmail
    .Display 'Show the email

End With

Set newEmail = Nothing
Set appOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have spent several hours searching Google and Stack Overflow to no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution thanks to [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164142/reading-htm-file-to-htmlbody-vba)

We need to save our template as HTML, then manually create a new email using the HTML code.

I'm yet to add images to the code but I think this will be easy using a find and replace method.

Final code without images:

```
Option Explicit

Sub openEmail(rownum As Integer)

Dim cfgFromEmail As String
Dim cfgNotice As String
Dim cfgTemplate As String
Dim appOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim newEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim htmlPath As String

'Dim rownum As Integer
'Dim colnum As Integer

'rownum = 6

cfgFromEmail = Sheets("Email").Range("O5").Value
cfgNotice = Sheets("Email").Cells(rownum, 10) '10 = column J
cfgTemplate = Sheets("Email").Cells(rownum, 11) '11 = column K
htmlPath = "\\shared\drive\path\to\template\goes\here\" & cfgTemplate & ".htm"

Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'Creates a blank email

If cfgNotice <> "null" Then 'If is not blank
    MsgBox cfgNotice, vbInformation, "Before you send the email"
End If

With newEmail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = cfgFromEmail
    .HTMLBody = HTMLtoString(htmlPath)
    'Refer to and fill in variable items in template
    '.Body = Replace(.Body, "<< clientname >>", Worksheets("Clients").Range(1, 2))
    '.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "&lt;&lt; clientname &gt;&gt;", Worksheets("Clients").Range(1, 2))
    .Display 'Show the email

End With

Set newEmail = Nothing
Set appOutlook = Nothing

End Sub

Function HTMLtoString(htmlPath As String)
    'Returns a string after reading the contents of a given file
    HTMLtoString = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(htmlPath).ReadAll()

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If the email template is not too complicated, you may be able to just create a new email and create the template without signature using HTML:

```
Sub emailgenerator

    Dim appOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim newEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim emailBody As String

    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set newEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    emailBody = "<p>Header</p><br><p>body area or something</p>"
    emailBody = emailBody & "<table></table>" ' maybe add tables and whatever is needed

    With newEmail 
        .To = "abc@abc.com"
        .CC = "def@def.com"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "youremail@youremail.com" ' could disregard this
        .HTMLBody = emailBody
        .Save
        .Close olPromptForSave
    End With

End Sub
```

This will take some looking into HTML but you can probably recreate the template with enough effort.

I believe when I tried this method for another project my signature wasn't getting appended automatically as it would with a template but not sure... best of luck

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the HTML code in the template is quite long so not sure this solution would work.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's looking for solutions not involving parsing HTML tags, here's a relatively simple one.  Make sure to have the Microsoft Word library referenced.

```
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim myDoc As Word.Document

Set myItem = _
    Outlook.Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(TemplateName & ".oft")

    .Display
    Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set myDoc = myInspector.WordEditor

 myDoc.Bookmarks("_MailAutoSig").Range.Delete
```